# URL redirection in Wordpress manually by editing .htaccess file

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

please help me to fix my one of wordpress problem with URL redirecting in PHP.

This is my original wordpress htaccess file.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I want to create custom URL redirection here. For ex.,
I want to redirect pages,

```
http://example.com/b/1    >     http://example.com/b?n=1
http://example.com/b/2    >     http://example.com/b?n=2
```

i am using directory URL type (displaying URLs as directories without extensions) SEO options in wordpress settings.

inside of http://example.com/b page, I have included another php file using ‘`include(‘z.php’);`’ command.
`Z.php` is reading URL parameter comes from `‘/?n=1’` through redirected URL. 
I tried below solution, but no luck..

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^b/([^/]*)$ /b/?n=$1 

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Appreciate any of help.

**EDIT**

wordpress header file can read the translated parameters. i checked that by displaying `GET` parameter `'n'` in title. 
but it shows file not found for `http://example.com/b/`

i verified that, by editing `http://example.com/b/` page content. non of page content displaying after rewriting.

Any help appreciated

**EDIT**

URL may have characters in parameter as below.

```
http://example.com/b/abc_1    >     http://example.com/b?n=abc_1
http://example.com/b/aa_2    >     http://example.com/b?n=aa_2
```

Thanks for Helping

Comment: Append flags to your rule `[L,QSA]`

Comment: its not worked. when i added, it gives error 500. when i removed only 'L' it not gives error. but not works redirection properly.

Comment: How you are entering url in the address bar?

Comment: it gives 'page not found' message
i am using http://example.com/b/1

Comment: Finally it is /index.php?n=1. Can't see any special script for /b/?n=1

Comment: yes finally it will be example.com/b/index.php?n=1 .
becasue im using directory naming in SEO options, its using example.com/b/?n=1

Comment: i think, my internal including page not reading redirected URL's parameters. can it be happen?

Comment: It depends on where the .htaccess is located. `RewriteRule ^b/([^/]*)$ b/index.php?n=$1 [L]` and below `RewriteRule . b/index.php [L]` instead of `RewriteRule . /index.php [L]`

Comment: htaccess file is at root folder. and including files also at root directory..

Comment: Included file works in the main script context.

Comment: actually im including some custom codes. not wordpress files.

Comment: So in the root htaccess path must be rewriten from `b/2` to `b/index.php?n=2`. It is not clear about index.php at the root.

Comment: i am using directory mode url creation at wordpress settings. so page url is example.com/b/ . this url not including any file name becasue of wordpress settings.  permalink of page is example.com/b/

Comment: Worpress has his own Rewrite settings in Admin panel. Check settings

Comment: Seems Wordpress parses `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` to retrieve data, so using of `.htaccess` is not make sense. All URLs must point to the index.php.

Comment: hi this one fix using htaccess tester see the bellow answer.

Comment: I think you're approaching this problem the wrong way. What does `n` represent? What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the word press related solution for this question.

in word press all the requests are heading to index.php automatically. if we create custom rewrite to another page, that request not going through index.php. that makes wordpress unidentified request and wordpress will return page not found message.

becasue of that, we have to redirect custom rewrite to `index.php` instead of permalink.

i used

```
RewriteRule ^b/([^/]*)$ index.php?page_id=4&n=$1
```

this rule redirected all requests matched with rule to index page. (my page ID for `/b/` is 4) 
this worked successfully for me.

other solutions above worked for non wordpress situations. but i found wordpress behavior as i explained.

appreciates who tried to answer.

Comment: Ah ok, now got it, it was unclear for me that you are willing to use just one single specific page as target.

Answer (score 1):

At first sight it seems to me that it should be

```
RewriteRule ^b/([^/]*)$ /?p=$1
```

Wordpress doesn't know what to do with the url `/b?n=X`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want `http://example.com/b/abc_1` to work, the `abc_1` part must match the slug of a wordpress post.

Additionally you have to change the settings->permalink structure to match either postname or a custom structure like `/b/%postname%`.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
http://example.com/b/1
```

**to**

```
http://example.com/b?n=1
```

**Using this**

```
RewriteRule ^b/([0-9]+)/?$ b?n=$1 [NC,L]


<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^b/([0-9]+)/?$ b?n=$1 [NC,L]
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

[image]
[image]
[Test hear](http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/)

[More info](http://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/)

Comment: hi, as i mentioned in edited part of question, rewriting rule working properly. i verified that by reading parameters in header file and it worked. but problem is wordpress not shows page contents other than, header page and side bar.
thanks

Comment: no luck still. that wont worked. please notify that, im using Wordpress URL rewriting option (display urls without file names) in wordpress settings. when opening page, header.php file can read the converted parameters. (that means conversion happening correctly). header, side bar and footer shows without problem. but page body says page not found. that means, converted URL (example.com/b/?n=1) is not found by page body.

Comment: its using 'Post Name' permalink setting in wordpress

Answer (score 0):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^b/([^/]*)$ /b/?n=$1 

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
#add below line
RewriteRule ^b/([0-9]+)/$ http://example.com/b?n=$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```