# wordpress page not found message after writing correct URL rewrite

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have default wordpress htaccess file and i added new rule. URL translation is happening successfully. but, wordpress page says 'page not found'. when i load page with parameters manually, its working properly.

.htaccess file rules

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^abc/(.*)$ abc/?n=$1 [QSA]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

any help will be appreciated

Comment: Set the Flag `L` to say "if found, here is the end,..": `RewriteRule ^abc/(.*)$ abc/?n=$1 [QSA,L]`

Comment: its made a 500 error. not worked..

Comment: i found the answer at

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23700518/url-redirection-in-wordpress-manually-by-editing-htaccess-file][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23700518/url-redirection-in-wordpress-manually-by-editing-htaccess-file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check your error_log , there must be some loop of redirects.

Regards

Suyash

Comment: i checked, but no errors found. wordpress showing, header, sidebar and footer correctely. but body part says page not found

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress actually uses those IDs only to fetch the post. The url in text format is converted to post_id. I believe then you must switch on the debug in your wordpress installation.

You can enable the debug by adding the following line in your wp-config.php

```
define('WP_DEBUG', true);
```

You also enable the logging of errors. By adding the following

```
define('WP_DEBUG_LOG', true);
```

WP_DEBUG_LOG is a companion to WP_DEBUG that causes all errors to also be saved to a debug.log log file inside the /wp-content/ directory.

Second , as you are saying that wordpress is dispplaying everything else except your content body part , it also implies that there is nothing related to php error , because wordpress will stop at the point where php phase the issue and here you are saying that wordpress is displaying footer too that means php translation gone through fully.

Third it means the query to retrieve the post had something , does your theme shows any error if not matching post found in coding. Also check your theme single.php.

Regards

Suyash Jain